# Visual Studio Have to Click Button Twice

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, button, gridview, sqldatasource

I'm trying to write code that will, at the click of a button, push a string variable onto a page and then open that page.  The trouble that I am running into is that variable, a button's text, is nested within a gridview, making accessing it difficult.  It is also difficult because I am importing it from an SQL database into the Gridview, so I cannot access it directly from there either.  It works with my current code if I use the button's onClick event, but then for some reason I have to click the button twice in order for it to work.  I have read on here to instead use the onPreRender event, but that interferes with pushing the string variable onto the page, and I can't have that.  Is there any other way to get rid of having to click the button twice that doesn't involve the onPreRender event?

Here is the code:

```vb
    Imports System.Data.SqlClient
    Imports System.IO

    Partial Class PartsLookup
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


        Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        End Sub

        Private Function FindControlRecursive(ByVal RootControl As Control, ByVal ControlID As String) As Control
            If RootControl.ID = ControlID Then
                Return RootControl
            End If

            For Each controlToSearch As Control In RootControl.Controls
                Dim controlToReturn As Control = FindControlRecursive(controlToSearch, ControlID)
                If controlToReturn IsNot Nothing Then
                    Return controlToReturn
                End If
            Next
            Return Nothing
        End Function

        Protected Sub Button1Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
            Dim clickedButton As Button = sender
            MsgBox(clickedButton.Text)
            Dim ControlText As Control = FindControlRecursive(GridView1, clickedButton.ID)
            Dim ControlText1 As Button = ControlText
            Dim MachineNumber As String = ControlText1.Text
            If MachineNumber = "" Then
                ControlText1.Visible = False
            End If
            Dim SpecificPart() As String = {String that is the files contents, the middle of which is where the variable will be pushed to}
            Dim path As String = "File path where the variable is to be pushed to"
            File.WriteAllLines(path, SpecificPart)
            clickedButton.PostBackUrl = "~/PartNumberPages/PartTemplate.aspx"
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Comment: You could try adding Handles clauses to your subroutines (or double clicking the button in the designer). Sometimes this will cause your code to fire twice, though. Should the method definition be Button1_Click?

Comment: Well, as the buttons are in a gridview, I can't interact with them directly like that.  If I double click I only add an event for the gridview, which I don't want.  The method definition is fine as Button1Click far as I know, it's just what i called it on the .aspx page.

Comment: Yuo should use [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) - it will point out some type mismatches, e.g. instead of `Dim clickedButton As Button = sender` you should have `Dim clickedButton As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)`.

Comment: Could you add the gridview markup? If it's a buttoncolumn it'll behave differently from a templatecolumn...(I actually prefer the templatecolumn approach)